# Unitary dilation of a rectangular contraction

Tags: linear-algebra, hilbert-spaces, contraction-operator

Given a contraction $A$ (which means $||A||\leqslant 1$) on a Hilbert space $H$, one can show that $A$ has a unitary dilation $U_A$ on a larger Hilbert space $K$, i.e. $A=P_H U_A|_H$. Let's say we're interested only in finite dimensional spaces. If we define a defect operator $D_A=\sqrt{1-A^{\dagger}A}$, an example of a unitary dilation is
\begin{equation*}
U_A=\left(
\begin{array}{cc}
A & -D_{A^{\dagger}} \\
D_A & A^{\dagger}
\end{array}
\right).
\end{equation*}
Here's the question: one can show that the above dilation is also unitary when $A$ is a rectangular (e.g. $A:\mathbb{C}^n\rightarrow\mathbb{C}^m,n\neq m$) contraction. However, in the literature it is always assumed that $A$ is square-dimensional. What is the reason of this assumption?

Comment: If $A$ is an operator on a finite dimensional Hilbert space, then $A:H \to H$, which means that $A$ is necessarily a square matrix anyway.

Comment: Yes, so that is a typical version of a fact that a contraction admits a unitary dilation. But, as stated later, it seems that a rectangular contraction $A$ also admits a unitary dilation, even in the form of a given example $U_A$. So I don't understand why we impose the condition "being an operator on $H$" from the beginning, instead of "being a homomorphism $H_1\rightarrow H_2$"?